# Difference between damped track vs track to

Tags: rigging, armature

Can anyone give a slight explanation, what the difference between these two and how can I use them in different situations?

Comment: These are the Blender manual description for [Damped Track](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/damped_track.html#damped-track-constraint) and [Track To](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/track_to.html#track-to-constraint).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a track-to as being a pair of sequential rotations.  First, we rotate about the "up" axis provided by the constraint; then, we rotate about the vector orthogonal to both the up axis and the (newly transformed) tracking axis:

[image]

A damped track is a single rotation, in the axis orthogonal to the initial tracking axis and the desired tracking axis:

[image]

While both of these track the target, there's a free axis of rotation there, the "roll" about the tracking axis, and these two constraints can give very different values for that.  This is most obvious when the rotation needed to track the target is large:

[image]

In terms of use, the damped track is the more "natural" constraint.  It leaves you with less rotation.  If we imagine the tracking bone/object to have two frictionless ball joints holding its ends in place, and we aim it by controlling its connecting pieces, we'll get behavior like a damped track constraint.

But some kinds of situations aren't natural like that.  When your camera operator turns your camera around, they don't rotate it in a single rotation axis; they rotate it such that its top remains pointed at the sky.  And camera tracking is the most reasonable use of a track-to constraint.